# Query Running Subtraction

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a project, in which I need to calculate all the due
payment. I've made a query in Query
Design. But I'm unable to make query to get total, paid amount, due
 amount and DueAmount column value will be subtracted from previous DueAmount value.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT Payment.PayDate, OrderMaster.OrderId, OrderMaster.CustomerName, OrderMaster.TotalAmount, Payment.PayAmount, OrderMaster.TotalAmount - Payment.PayAmount AS DueAmount FROM OrderMaster INNER JOIN Payment ON OrderMaster.OrderId = Payment.OrderId;
```

I'm getting the query result like this:

```
   PayDate   | OrderId  | CustomerName | TotalAmount | PayAmount | DueAmount
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   20/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  2000      | 3000
   22/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  1000      | 4000
   25/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  2000      | 3000
```

I want the query result like this:

```
    PayDate   | OrderId | CustomerName | TotalAmount | PayAmount | DueAmount
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   20/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  2000      | 3000
   22/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  1000      | 2000
   25/12/2014 |     1   | Someone      |   5000      |  2000      | 0
```

Please help me to make the exact query to get this result. Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged your question with MySQL, SQL Server and MS Access. Which of those three are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> You may try like this:
> ```

```
select myField, myField -
(select myField from myTable where myOrderField =
(select max(myOrderField) from myTable where myOrderField < T.myOrderField))
as RunningDiff
from myTable as T
```